# React hook forms with nested fields array from an async source returns empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

Following this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-nested-arrays-x7btr?file=/src/nestedFieldArray.js) of nested arrays, I'm trying to display the following data:

```
 { array: [
    {
        { "last_received_date": "2020-08-03 11:04:18 UTC+8", "tasks": [
            { "id": "1", "freq": "d", "prog": 0, "max": 5, "reward": 1000 },
            { "id": "2", "freq": "d", "prog": 0, "max": 1, "reward": 1000 },
            { "id": "3", "freq": "d", "prog": 0, "max": 3, "reward": 1000 }]
        }
    }, 
    { everything like above but more }
]}
```

This is a long one, and I'm not well-versed in react hooks myself, so please bear with me. **My problem is that the `fields` in my nested field returns an empty array, if probed or queried any further.** Here's a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-dream-331qc) to a sandbox I made (as far as I could emulate it).

Here's the nested field:

```
export default function TaskFields({ nestIndex, control, register, errors }) {
    const { fields, remove } = useFieldArray({ control, 
        name: `array[${nestIndex}].challenges` 
    });
    const indexMap = ['Daily', 'Weekly'];
    return (
        <Box>
            {fields.map((task, j) => { // Should repeat thrice, but fields is apparently empty
                return (
                <Box key={j}>
                    <Button variant="danger" onClick={() => {remove(j);}} size="small" }>x</Button>
                    ID: <input name={indexMap[nestIndex] + `task[${j}].id`}  ref={register()} defaultValue={task.id} />                     
                    Freq: // Same as above
                    Prog: // Same as above
                    Max Prog: // Same as above
                    Reward: // Same as above
                </Box> );
            })}
        </Box> );
}
```

Notice the `name: array[${nestIndex}].challenges` part; if displayed via `console.log`, it returns an empty array. If I remove the `[${nestIndex}].challenges` from it, it returns the complete data set (the value of `array`). But that outer part of the data has already been dealt with, and displayed, here:

The primary field:

```
export default function TaskTypeCards({ control, register, errors }) {
const { fields } = useFieldArray({ control, name: "array" });   
const indexMap = ['Daily', 'Weekly'];
return (
    <Box>
        {fields.map((item, i) => { // Will repeat twice, since there are two objects in the array
            return (
                <Box key={i}>
                    Title: {indexMap[i]}
                    Last Received Date: // This will display the last received date
                    <TaskFields data={item} nestIndex={i} {...{ control, register, errors }}/> 
                    // This should display the array of objects in 'tasks'
                </Box>
            )
        })}
    </Box> );
}
```

The above works fine, and displays two boxes with the `Last Received Date`, meaning the `fields` there retained the data I needed from the form, below:

```
export default UserTaskForm (data) {
    const [challengeData, setChallengeData] = useState({});
    const { register, control, handleSubmit, setError, reset, errors } = useForm(challengeData);
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            let result = await dbGetUserTasks(data.userId); // Gets results from API
            let challengeData = JSON.parse(result[0].data)); // Looks like the data above
            setChallengeData(challengeData);
            reset(challengeData);
        }
        fetchData();        
    }, [reset]);    
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <Button type="submit" style={{ marginLeft: "auto" }}>Save Changes</Button>
            {challengeData ? <TaskTypeCards {...{ control, register, errors }} /> : null}
        </form> );
}
```

So what I'm left with is two boxes with the `Last Received Data`, but nothing of the tasks that are listed therein, which is far from the example I linked above.

I've tried replacing the `array[${nestIndex}].challenges` with just `array` in the `name` of TaskFields, and then replaced the `fields.map` to `fields[nestIndex].challenges.map` which does work in displaying the data, but the delete button does deletes the entire object under array, not an object under tasks, presumably because `fields` there is set to array.

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: could you reproduce this on codesandbox?

Comment: @hgb123, I'll try, and post up a link. Not sure how I'll do the API call though.

Comment: you could mock the data by json file

Comment: @hgb123here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-dream-331qc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw two things to notice here

First is that the nested is `tasks` not `challenges`

```js
// UserTaskFields.js
// ...
const { fields, remove } = useFieldArray({
  control,
  name: `array[${nestIndex}].tasks`,
})
// ...
```

Second, you used `challengeData` with default state of empty object `{}` to conditionally render if the object is not empty. But you might not remember that `Boolean({}) === true`, so that you accidentally render from the beginning, even before fetching data. So a solution might be using `Object.keys(challengeData).length > 0` instead, or just use a boolean value of `fetched` for simplicity

```js
const x = {}

console.log(Boolean(x))

console.log(x ? 'foo' : 'bar')
```

```js
// UserTaskForm.js
const [challengeData, setChallengeData] = useState({});
const [fetched, setFetched] = useState({});
// ...

// This will always render because Boolean({}) return true
{challengeData ? <TaskTypeCards {...{ control, register, errors }} /> : null}

// => should be
{Object.keys(challengeData).length > 0 ? <TaskTypeCards {...{ control, register, errors }} /> : null}

// => other way
{fetched? <TaskTypeCards {...{ control, register, errors }} /> : null}
```

Below is my forked codesandbox with the fix

[image: Edit compassionate-galileo-nkz71]

Comment: Whoops, I forgot about those, I usually rename my variables before posting online, just in case. In any case, thanks, the 'fetched' really did it.